# Dapper Object State tracking

Tags: c#, winforms, dapper

Some background:
I'm writing a Winforms based LOB application and have read a lot of "hate" towards datatables, datasets, tableadapters, etc. I'm not a huge fan of OR\M's, but found dapper to be great. I get the speed of pure ADO without writing ADO.

The question:
I need to maintain object state to know whether it's an insert, update, or delete.

How would you go about this? An enum field of the object you set in the form when certain buttons are pushed maybe?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not have two properties: `IsDeleted`, `IsModified`.  You'll know its a new (INSERT) object because it won't have a primary key yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with the comments from @maccettura above, I would look into using an additional Dapper extension - [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib).

> Dapper.Contrib contains a number of helper methods for inserting,
>   getting, updating and deleting records.

You can set things up via convention or attributes.

Comment: I looked into contrib for the automatic change tracking , but didn't see any way to control the magic insert, update, delete methods. I would like them to be powered by stored procs.

Comment: What do you mean by control? It supports insert, update, and delete - it has explicit methods for them. When you insert & update, it sets the key.

Comment: For instance .Update() is generating an update statement and executing it behind the scenes that I have no control over. I don't need autogenerated sql, just change tracking to know which of my own stored procs to call.

Comment: Understood. Well, Dapper is open source. You could download the contrib and modify it to use your stored procedures instead.